# How non English text like Hindi or Chinese is stored in the sql database internally ? Which is the best data type to store them

Tags: sql, database

How non English text like Hindi or Chinese is stored in the sql database internally ? Which is the best data type to store them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use the UTF8_general_ci

Comment: But Why.. ? and How can implement it efficiently

Comment: for more informations about the character encoding you can read more about it in this link : http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html#whyutf8 .